# fast method to calculate p-values from .lm.fit()

Tags: r, lm

I am running simulations and fitting linear models with [`.lm.fit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pbdDMAT/versions/0.4-2/topics/lm.fit). Although extremely fast, this function does not provide the predictors' p-values. Is there a fast way to compute them (maybe from the values returned by `.lm.fit()`)? I am aware of [this](https://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304) method to calculate approximate p-values, but I need the exact ones.

**Update**:
Dirk Eddelbuettel provided the fastest way to fit the lm and Ben Bolker a method to compute the p-values, by combining both answers we get:

```
set.seed(101)
X <- cbind(1,matrix(1:10))
y <- rnorm(10)

mdl <- RcppArmadillo::fastLmPure(X, y)

pval <- 2*pt(abs(mdl$coefficients/mdl$stderr), mdl$df.residual, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726516/r-fastest-lm-method-to-compute-coefficients-std-error-and-p-values) got closed as a duplicate, but now that you have these answers, maybe worth deleting that one?

Comment: Not gonna lie, it feels like witchcraft when I run 18,000 regressions in 4 seconds instead of 2 minutes, but this post is going to save me a lot of time! Many thanks to mat, Dick and Ben.

Comment: @C.Murtaugh Glad it could help. It is *Dirk*, by the way ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dirk's answer will be faster, but in case it's convenient here's the implementation in pure R (extracting the bits you need from `summary.lm`, and assuming there are no issues with non-full-rank model matrices etc.)

Example:

```
set.seed(101)
X <- cbind(1,matrix(1:10))
y <- rnorm(10)
m <- .lm.fit(X,y)
```

p-value calcs:

```
rss <- sum(m$residuals^2)
rdf <- length(y) - ncol(X)
resvar <- rss/rdf
R <- chol2inv(m$qr)
se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
2*pt(abs(m$coef/se),rdf,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Compare with:

```
coef(summary(lm(y~X-1)))[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
```

Comment: Nice. There is always the issue of computing with/without an intercept which requires a slight adjustment as I re-learn each time I visit the R side of `fastLm` and their summary methods.

Answer (score 2):

For this issue (of getting standard errors and hence p-values) I wrote three different versions of a function `fastLm()` in package RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen and RcppGSL.  Part of it is of course also just for exposition. But you could start there.  Make sure you use the `fastLmPure()` variants taking a vector and matrix and *not* the formula interface -- all the time is spent deparsing the formula.

Here, just for kicks, is the RcppArmadillo variant:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fastLm_impl(const arma::mat& X, const arma::colvec& y) {
    int n = X.n_rows, k = X.n_cols;

    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);    // fit model y ~ X
    arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;           // residuals

    // std.errors of coefficients
    double s2 = std::inner_product(res.begin(), res.end(), 
                                   res.begin(), 0.0)/(n - k);

    arma::colvec std_err = 
         arma::sqrt(s2 *
                    arma::diagvec(arma::pinv(arma::trans(X)*X)));  

    return List::create(Named("coefficients") = coef,
                        Named("stderr")       = std_err,
                        Named("df.residual")  = n - k);
}
```