# Linear model. How to fix my very slow R loop?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have some specific linear regression model Y~X. My task is to repeat the generation of X and Y and some other steps 1000 times. For each of the sub-problems estimate the expected number of the false discoveries. I wrote a code, but it is working about... 10 minutes for k = 2, and than I have k = 950... so... What can I change in my code, to speed it up?

```
testing <- function(k){
  M <- matrix(0,1000,1)
  for (i in 1:1000){
    X <- matrix(rnorm(1000*950, 0, 0.1), nrow=1000, ncol=950)
    B <- c(rep(3, times=5), rep(0, times=945))
    eps <- rnorm(1000)
    Y <- X %*% B + eps
    lmodel <- lm(Y ~ X-1)
    beta1 <- lmodel$coefficients 
    beta <- sort(beta1, index.return=TRUE, decreasing = TRUE)
    X2 <- X[,beta$ix]
    Y <- X2 %*% B + eps
    lm1 <- lm(Y ~ X[ ,1:k]-1)
    p.value <- summary(lm1)$coefficients[1, 4]
    M[i,1] = ifelse(p.value < 0.05, 1, 0)
  }
  return(sum(M)/1000)
}

testing(1) #0.328
testing(10)
```

Comment: X array is pretty big. Can you scale down it?

Comment: The task says, X is a matrix 1000×950, its elements are iid random
variables from N(0, 0.1)

Comment: Small bickies, but the vector B never changes, so you only need to calculate it once, before the loop.

Comment: That's true, thanks! But it doesn't make the loop faster

Comment: I went to sleep and made my code run for all of k = {1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 950}. After the night I fortunately have my results (lmao)

Comment: Good news! All the time was in `lmodel <- lm(Y ~ X-1)` so hard to recode. If you couldn't shrink X, the next thing you could do is parallelise, which for this problem would have helped a lot, I think.

Comment: I haven't had time to work this through, but one option is to use `lm.fit`, rather than `lm` as it is considerably quicker. You have to calculate the p-values yourself though, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732933/fast-method-to-calculate-p-values-from-lm-fit